# How to publish a private Chrome app for my Google Apps organization?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-apps

I've found this article and I am trying to set up Chrome extensions for my organization.
https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/2663860?hl=en

The guide instructs to navigate to

> Device management > Chrome management > User settings > Chrome Web
>   Store Permissions.

However, I cannot find **User Settings**.

This is what I see under **Chrome management**:

[image]

Has anyone done this before, and could someone please help me to publish a private app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshot you've linked is of the **Apps** section for core services, not **Device management**. That being said, I'm guessing you have not purchased Chrome device licenses so you're probably not seeing the same view as what's being shown in the article you've linked.

In that **Apps** section, you'll want to go to **Additional Google services**. There, you'll see **Chrome Management** at the top of the list and clicking on that will expose the **User settings** you're looking for.

Please note, this has nothing to do with the actual publication of the app/extension, this is how you'll actually push out the app/extension to users as a policy. Once you publish an app/extension, you'll be able to manage it with [these settings](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/2657289).

Comment: Thank you for the extensive explanation. However, I do not see `Chrome Management` listed inside Additional Google services.

Comment: In the top right, there is what looks to be an upside-down pyramid. This is the filter on the services. Click that and then unselect "Show top featured services." I don't recall if this hides Chrome Management or not but it should then show you everything that is available.